# Placing UITextView on top of keyboard?

Tags: swift

When my view controller pops up, I already call the keyboard. All I want to do is **place a UITextView directly above the keyboard.** I could hardcode it, but am worried about different keyboard sizes. Any ideas ?

```
@IBOUtlet var textView: UITextView! = UITextView()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` notification to know when the keyboard has come up. You can use the keyboard frame from this notification to dynamically calculate the position of this `UITextField`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyBoardDidShow(notification :NSNotification)
{
   if let frameObject: AnyObject = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
   {
        let keyboardRect = frameObject.CGRectValue()
        // use keyboardRect to calculate the frame of the textfield
   }
}
```

For more information read
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keyboard_Notification_User_Info_Keys